# Store Array of #s to NSUserDefaults, Add Checkmark to each cell row that matches a # in array

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

In an app I previously had help with here, I parse an XML located online, show only 1 item from the XML the first day, and add an item each day after that the app gets opened.  I would like to be able to add a 'Mark As Read' action to each cell's detail view.  This way, the user could read it, mark it as read, and on subsequent loads, a checkmark would appear next to each item loaded.

Since the app downloads the XML each time, here is the idea I thought may work the best to do this.  I was thinking of having an array stored to a NSUserDefault Key.  This array would have a number added to it based off what row they selected.  If they selected row 1 and marked it, the array would add the #1 to it.  If they then selected row 3 and marked it, the array would have 1 & 3 in it.

Is this something doable, and then in cellForRowAtIndexPath, have it add a checkmark to each row # that is included in the array?

I have the idea in my head, and if this works, just need a little guidance for implementing it.  Thanks

**UPDATE**
Here is what little I do have so far.  In the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I check if the NSUserDefault key 'checkedrows' exists.  If not, I create it with an object of an empty array.

```
if (![defaults objectForKey:@"checkedrows"]) {
        [defaults setObject:@[] forKey:@"checkedrows"];
    }
```

The two main questions I have is how to in the cellForRowAtIndexPath get the numbers that are in the array, and if any rows match them, add a checkmark to it.  Example:  There are 5 rows in the tableview, and the array returns 0, 2, 4.  So, I want the TableView to add a checkmark to first third and fifth cells.

The other main question is how to go about adding a number into the array, without deleting any of the old numbers.

Comment: Keep in mind that this logic will break if you alter (add/remove) or reorder the data presented in the tableview...

Comment: @Alladinian The app works that only one row is added at a time, and new rows are always added at the top of the tableview.  So, the row # of rows should never change.  See edit I'm about to make to question for what I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely!

You can use the `setObject:forKey:` method to write an `NSArray` object to `NSUserDefaults`, and `objectForKey:` to retrieve that array.

Now, simply listen out for

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in your `UITableViewDelegate`, retrieve the array already existing in the `NSUserDefaults`, add the index that was just tapped (get this info. from the `indexPath` object) to the array, and simply write the array back to `NSUserDefaults`!

To add a checkmark to selected cells, use the following command inside the`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method above:

```
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Comment: In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, how do I have it add a checkmark to any row whose number matches a number stored in said array?

Comment: check if indexPath.row is in your array, if so add a checkmark.

Comment: @Martol1ni I realize that is what needs to happen, just don't know how to get the array from NSUserDefaults for that, and then how to check if the number for the row exists.  I edited original question just now.

Comment: To get the array from NSUserDefaults, use:
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSUserDefaults sharedDefaults] objectForKey:@"keyYouUsedToStoreTheArray"];

Comment: To add an integer to the NSMutableArray, you have to use the NSInteger class.
To check if a number exists in the NSMutableArray, use the method containsObject: on it, where the object that you pass in is an NSInteger object initialized with an int that you want to find.

Comment: So, when a new row is marked, I could get the array from the key, and then add the number row to it, and add that array to the object for the key and then synchronize?  How do you add a number to an array ?

Comment: Guess specifically I need to be able to do something like if(indexPath.row containsANumberInArray) do the checkmark.

Comment: To add a number to an array, use NSInteger *integer = [NSInteger integerWithInt:int]; or something along those lines.

Comment: This worked as I asked the question, but due to way rows were sorted, I ended up doing this a different way, but if anyone else wants to do what the question asked, this is perfect.